# How can I evaluate the mAP of a frozen graph using the tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have tried loading the frozen graph instead of the checkpoints editing the eval*.py but seems like it requires variables like "global_step" etc.

Comment: Your question lacks minimal requirements. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask an appropriate question

Comment: I would also be very interested in how to evaluate frozen pb graph files!